# What are good materials to diffuse/scatter 850nm infrared light?

Tags: optics, infrared-radiation, optical-materials

I want to properly light up a room with an IR Illuminator, but most illuminators lack diffusion, therefore shadows are especially sharp and bold. Since IR rays don't behave like visible light rays, it's hard to find materials that properly scatter those rays. I've tried putting fabrics and frosted plastic in front, but it just seems to go right through.

Comment: Who says "IR rays don't behave like visible light rays"? Roughened plastic or glass should work just fine to diffuse an IR beam.

Comment: @ThePhoton Will a "softbox" or cloth diffusers work? IR seems to penetrate fabrics easier than visible light.